# Funciones Python. Extraer archivos de un .zip, y ordenarles en directorios según las columnas de un archivo csv

Tags: python, funciones, csv, opencv, zip

Tengo un archivo .zip con varios ficheros .txt y un archivo .csv

El archivo .csv contiene dos columnas una  "type" que define el tipo de fichero .txt y otra "name" que contiene los  nombres de los archivos.

Tengo que crear una función que descomprime el archivo .zip y ordene los archivos .txt en diferentes directorios según el tipo que describe el archivo .csv con el separador ;

He llegado unicamente exportar los archivos, encontrar el archivo csv y abrirlo, pero no consigo crear los directorios nuevos según los valores de columna "type" y mover los archivos .txt correspondientes a dichos directorios.

```
import csv
from zipfile import ZipFile


zip_path = "data/arteDeCozina.zip"
              
def deompress_data(zip_path):
    with zf.ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as zip_f:
    zip_path.extractall()
    for name in zip_path.namelist():
        if name.lower().endswith('.csv'):
        with zipFile.open(name) as file:
```

csv es el siguiente:

```
    name                          type
0   aceyte_de_almendras_sin_fuego   varios
1   aceyte_de_huevos    varios
2   adobos_4e_solomillos    fiambres
3   agraz_para_todo_el_año  varios
4   aguja_paladar   pescados
5   alberchigos     conservas
6   albondiguilla_1_de_borrajas     verduras
7   albondiguillas_castellanas  carnes-carnero
8   albondiguillas_de_ave   carnes-ave
9   albondiguillas_de_el_sollo  pescados
10  albondiguillas_de_pan_rallado_y_grasa   carnes-ternera
```

Comment: ¿un ejemplo del csv ese?

Comment: hola @abulafia añado una parte del csv más arriba en el cuerpo del post. Los nombres de los archivos están en la columna "name" mientras los titulos de directiorios que tengo que crear deberían tener los nombres de la columna type. Muchas gracias por intentar ayudarme!